# Exporting variables from Shell script and accessing it in Python script

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables, sh

I am trying to export a variable from my shell script and then access it from my python script.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    test="hello, python!!!"
    export test
    python test.py
```

My Python script is as follows:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import os
    text = os.environ.get("test")
    print(text)
```

After I source my shell script I dont see the printed output on command line. Instead, I see:

```
    shell_script:export:3: not valid in this context: test^M
```

But if I individually echo or run the python script after sourcing the shell script, I am able to get the desired result. Any ideas on how to do it in one go??

Comment: Is the first line of your shell script actually `#!/bin/bash`?  (As posted, it does not begin with `#`)

Comment: edited. It begins with #

Comment: This works for me.  Please edit the question to show how you're running the script.

Comment: try to run `dos2unix` on your shell script (the `^M` seems to indicate that you have a dos line ending..)

Comment: Actually the script worked properly (at least on my windows machine), please modify your question so that we can really help you since the "problem" you have is not really a problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  dos2unix worked.